# carousel slider is not having a smooth transition while sliding

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, swiper.js

I was trying to inspire the below same carrousel slider using the swiper js library. I am facing a problem in which the slider is not smoothly transitioning while clicking on the navigation arrows which is present right below the slider. I've tried adding the manual css transition effects but that didn't work. The slider has the smooth sliding effect while using the hardware keyboard arrow keys or mouse click and drag. Any help would be appreciated.

```js
const not_active_slide_scale_value = 0.85;
const not_active_slide_opacity_value = 0.4;

var swiper_scale_active = new Swiper("[swiper_scale_active]", {
  slidesPerView: 1.5,
  parallax: true,
  loop: true,
  breakpoints: {
    320: {
      speed: 900 /* Duration of transition between slides (in ms) */ ,
      slidesPerView: 1.2,
    },
    640: {
      speed: 1400,
    },
  },
  keyboard: {
    enabled: true,
  },
  centeredSlides: true,
  loop: true,
  slideToClickedSlide: true,
  spaceBetween: 0,
  grabCursor: true,
  navigation: {
    nextEl: "[btn_group] [next2]",
    prevEl: "[btn_group] [prev2]",
  },
  effect: "creative",
  creativeEffect: {
    limitProgress: 2, // slides after 2nd before/after active will have same state
    prev: {
      opacity: not_active_slide_opacity_value,
      scale: not_active_slide_scale_value,
      translate: ["-90%", 0, 0],
    },
    next: {
      opacity: not_active_slide_opacity_value,
      scale: not_active_slide_scale_value,
      translate: ["90%", 0, 0],
    },
  },
});

/* CUSTOM ARROWS CODE (WE want 5 click on next will change 5 slides - the speed is 0) */
const prev = document.querySelector("[btn_group] [prev]");
prev.addEventListener("click", prev_slide);

function prev_slide() {
  swiper_scale_active.slidePrev(0);
}

const next = document.querySelector("[btn_group] [next]");
next.addEventListener("click", next_slide);

function next_slide() {
  swiper_scale_active.slideNext(0);
}

/* API event example (Not in use in this code) */
swiper_scale_active.on("slideChange", function() {
  console.log("slide changed");
});

swiper_scale_active.on("keyPress", function(swiper, keyCode) {
  console.log(swiper);
  console.log("keyCode", keyCode);
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
  --main-bg-color: black;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

body {
  background: var(--main-bg-color);
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

[swiper_scale_active] .swiper-slide {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 20px;
  border-color: transparent;
  /* shadow */
  box-shadow: 0 0 100px 40px var(--main-bg-color);
  overflow: hidden;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  [swiper_scale_active] .swiper-slide {
    border-radius: 10px;
  }
}

[swiper_scale_active] .swiper-slide img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}


/* CUSTOM CSS "TRICK" => the link should work only on the active slide  */

[swiper_scale_active] .swiper-slide:not(.swiper-slide-active) a {
  pointer-events: none;
}


/* #### CUSTOM NEXT/PREV #### */

[btn_group] {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 16px;
}

[btn_group] button {
  background: transparent;
  padding: 10px 16px;
  border-width: 0px;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0.4;
  transition: opacity 0.5s linear;
}

[btn_group] button:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

[btn_group] svg {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.css" />
<br>
<h1><a style="color: white;" target="_blank" href="https://swiperjs.com/">Swiper 11</a> - Scale Active Slide (API Creative Effect)</h1><br><br>

<div swiper_scale_active class="swiper">
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/623/1600/900" />
      <a href="#" id="form">Link</a>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <div>
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/179/1600/900" />
        <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/25/1600/900" />
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div btn_group>
  <button prev>
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="12" height="19" fill="none" xmlns:v="https://vecta.io/nano"><path d="M10.485 17.971L2 9.485 10.485 1" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round"></path></svg>
  </button>
  <button next>
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="12" height="19" fill="none" xmlns:v="https://vecta.io/nano"><path d="M1.485 1l8.485 8.485-8.485 8.485" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round"></path></svg>
  </button>
</div>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Please look at the code snippet. Where are the navigation arrows?

Comment: There are 2 buttons in the html snippet which is acting as navigation arrows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a error (likely a typo) in your JS when assigning `nextEl` and `prevEl`.

- You have `nextEl: "[btn_group] [next2]", prevEl: "[btn_group] [prev2]"`
- It should be `nextEl: "[btn_group] [next]", prevEl: "[btn_group] [prev]"` because `[next2]` and `[prev2]` don't exist.

Updating those fixed it.

*FYI: I moved your buttons above the slideshow only because SO was hiding them with their console messages, and I couldn't see them or scroll to them.*

```js
const not_active_slide_scale_value = 0.85;
const not_active_slide_opacity_value = 0.4;

var swiper_scale_active = new Swiper("[swiper_scale_active]", {
  slidesPerView: 1.5,
  parallax: true,
  loop: true,
  breakpoints: {
    320: {
      speed: 900 /* Duration of transition between slides (in ms) */ ,
      slidesPerView: 1.2,
    },
    640: {
      speed: 1400,
    },
  },
  keyboard: {
    enabled: true,
  },
  centeredSlides: true,
  loop: true,
  slideToClickedSlide: true,
  spaceBetween: 0,
  grabCursor: true,
  navigation: {
    nextEl: "[btn_group] [next]",
    prevEl: "[btn_group] [prev]",
  },
  effect: "creative",
  creativeEffect: {
    limitProgress: 2, // slides after 2nd before/after active will have same state
    prev: {
      opacity: not_active_slide_opacity_value,
      scale: not_active_slide_scale_value,
      translate: ["-90%", 0, 0],
    },
    next: {
      opacity: not_active_slide_opacity_value,
      scale: not_active_slide_scale_value,
      translate: ["90%", 0, 0],
    },
  },
});

/* CUSTOM ARROWS CODE (WE want 5 click on next will change 5 slides - the speed is 0) */
const prev = document.querySelector("[btn_group] [prev]");
prev.addEventListener("click", prev_slide);

function prev_slide() {
  swiper_scale_active.slidePrev(0);
}

const next = document.querySelector("[btn_group] [next]");
next.addEventListener("click", next_slide);

function next_slide() {
  swiper_scale_active.slideNext(0);
}

/* API event example (Not in use in this code) */
swiper_scale_active.on("slideChange", function() {
  console.log("slide changed");
});

swiper_scale_active.on("keyPress", function(swiper, keyCode) {
  console.log(swiper);
  console.log("keyCode", keyCode);
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
  --main-bg-color: black;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

body {
  background: var(--main-bg-color);
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

[swiper_scale_active] .swiper-slide {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 20px;
  border-color: transparent;
  /* shadow */
  box-shadow: 0 0 100px 40px var(--main-bg-color);
  overflow: hidden;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  [swiper_scale_active] .swiper-slide {
    border-radius: 10px;
  }
}

[swiper_scale_active] .swiper-slide img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}


/* CUSTOM CSS "TRICK" => the link should work only on the active slide  */

[swiper_scale_active] .swiper-slide:not(.swiper-slide-active) a {
  pointer-events: none;
}


/* #### CUSTOM NEXT/PREV #### */

[btn_group] {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 16px;
}

[btn_group] button {
  background: transparent;
  padding: 10px 16px;
  border-width: 0px;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0.4;
  transition: opacity 0.5s linear;
}

[btn_group] button:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

[btn_group] svg {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.css" />
<br>
<h1><a style="color: white;" target="_blank" href="https://swiperjs.com/">Swiper 11</a> - Scale Active Slide (API Creative Effect)</h1><br><br>

<div btn_group>
  <button prev>
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="12" height="19" fill="none" xmlns:v="https://vecta.io/nano"><path d="M10.485 17.971L2 9.485 10.485 1" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round"></path></svg>
  </button>
  <button next>
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="12" height="19" fill="none" xmlns:v="https://vecta.io/nano"><path d="M1.485 1l8.485 8.485-8.485 8.485" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round"></path></svg>
  </button>
</div>

<div swiper_scale_active class="swiper">
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/623/1600/900" />
      <a href="#" id="form">Link</a>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <div>
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/179/1600/900" />
        <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/25/1600/900" />
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
```